# Proving a statement about equivalence relations.

Tags: solution-verification, relations, equivalence-relations

[image]

Am I doing it correctly? I am not sure about my notations and the way I explain things as this topic is very new to me..

**Question 3**

**a.** True

$E_{1}∩E_{2}$

**Reflexive:**

Since $E_{1}$ is an equivalent relation on A then for every $a ∈ A \ \ (a,a) ∈ E_{1}$.

Since $E_{2}$ is an equivalent relation on A then for every $a ∈ A \ \ (a,a) ∈ E_{2}$.

We can conclude that all elements of $E_{1}∩E_{2}$ are reflexive.

Therefore for every $a ∈ A \ \ (a,a) ∈ E_{1}∩E_{2}$.

**Symmetric:**

Since $E_{1}$ is an equivalent relation on A then for every $a,b ∈ A$ if $(a,b) ∈ E_{2}$, then $(b,a) ∈ E_{1}$.

Since $E_{2}$ is an equivalent relation on A then for every $a,b ∈ A$ if $(a,b) ∈ E_{2}$, then $(b,a) ∈ E_{2}$.

We can conclude that all elements of $E_{1}∩E_{2}$ are symmetric.

Therefore for every every $a,b ∈ A$ if $(a,b) ∈ E_{1}∩E_{2}$, then $(b,a) ∈ E_{1}∩E_{2}$.

**Transitive:**

Since $E_{1}$ is an equivalent relation on A then for every $a,b,c ∈ A$ if $(a,b),(b,c) ∈ E_{1}$, then $(a,c) ∈ E_{1}$.

Since $E_{2}$ is an equivalent relation on A then for every $a,b,c ∈ A$ if $(a,b),(b,c) ∈ E_{2}$, then $(a,c) ∈ E_{2}$.

We can conclude that all elements of $E_{1}∩E_{2}$ are transitive.

Therefore for every every $a,b,c ∈ A$ if $(a,b),(b,c) ∈ E_{1}∩E_{2}$, then $(a,c) ∈ E_{1}∩E_{2}$.

**b.** False.

$E_{1}∪E_{2}$

Counter example:

Let $A = \left\{1,2,3\right\}$

$E_{1} = \left\{\left(1,1\right),\left(1,2\right),\left(2,1\right),\left(2,2\right),\left(3,3\right)\right\}$

$E_{2} = \left\{\left(2,2\right),\left(2,3\right),\left(3,2\right),\left(3,3\right),\left(1,1\right)\right\}$.

Then $E_{1}∪E_{2} = \left\{\left(1,2\right),\left(2,1\right),\left(2,2\right),\left(2,3\right),\left(3,2\right),\left(3,3\right),\left(1,1\right)\right\}$

We can easily notice that $1R2 ∧ 2R3$, but $1R3$ is not part of the relation, which means the relation is not transitive, and therefore not an equivalence relation.

Comment: Everything is correct except that your counterexample misses $(3,3)$ from $E_1$ and $(1,1)$ from $E_2$.

Comment: Thanks I've fixed it! :)

Comment: "We can conclude that all elements of $E_1\cap E_2$ are reflexive."
The elements are not reflexive. The relation is reflexive.

Comment: Your proof of **a** is wrong. For example, to prove symmetry you need to begin choosing $(a,b) \in E_1\cap E_2$, then use the definition of intersection, then use the fact that $E_1$ and $E_2$ are symmetric, then use again the definition of intersection to conclude that $(b,a) \in E_1\cap E_2$